# python `list` and `for` return different results

Tags: python, list, generator

Why do `list` and `for` report different result if I use them on the values generated by my function?

```
from collections import deque

def neighbours(comp0, cand0):
    comp = deque([i for i in comp0])
    cand = deque([i for i in cand0])

    for i in range(len(cand)):
        elem = cand.popleft()
        comp.append(elem)
        yield comp, cand 
        comp.pop()
        cand.append(elem)

    return


>>> n = neighbours([2], [1,4,5])
>>> list(n)
[(deque([2]), deque([1, 4, 5])), (deque([2]), deque([1, 4, 5])), (deque([2]), deque([1, 4, 5]))]
>>> n = neighbours([2], [1,4,5])
>>> for i in n:
...  print(i)
... 
(deque([2, 1]), deque([4, 5]))
(deque([2, 4]), deque([5, 1]))
(deque([2, 5]), deque([1, 4]))
>>>
```

Comment: You return objects that are later modified. The difference is not the iteration method but that you print as you generate value or after generating them all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your objects are modified as you iterate; you are printing intermediate results when using `for`, final results when printing the list.

If you append the results to a list first, you get the same results as your `list()` output again:

```
>>> n = neighbours([2], [1,4,5])
>>> res = []
>>> for i in n:
...     print(i)
...     res.append(i)
... 
(deque([2, 1]), deque([4, 5]))
(deque([2, 4]), deque([5, 1]))
(deque([2, 5]), deque([1, 4]))
>>> res
[(deque([2]), deque([1, 4, 5])), (deque([2]), deque([1, 4, 5])), (deque([2]), deque([1, 4, 5]))]
```

Each element in `res` is a tuple with the *same two deque objects*:

```
>>> res[0][0] is res[1][0] is res[2][0]
True
>>> res[0][1] is res[1][1] is res[2][1]
True
```

You could yield `list()` copies of each `deque` instead, and thus create *new* objects:

```
>>> def neighbours(comp0, cand0):
...     comp = deque([i for i in comp0])
...     cand = deque([i for i in cand0])
...     for i in range(len(cand)):
...         elem = cand.popleft()
...         comp.append(elem)
...         yield list(comp), list(cand)
...         comp.pop()
...         cand.append(elem)
... 
>>> n = neighbours([2], [1,4,5])
>>> res = []
>>> for i in n:
...     print(i)
...     res.append(i)
... 
([2, 1], [4, 5])
([2, 4], [5, 1])
([2, 5], [1, 4])
>>> res
[([2, 1], [4, 5]), ([2, 4], [5, 1]), ([2, 5], [1, 4])]
```

Comment: about 5 seconds quicker than I wanted to post, super quick!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the problem has been well explained by **Javier**. Now if you want same results using iteration you can use:

```
>>> [i for i in n]
[(deque([2]), deque([1, 4, 5])), (deque([2]), deque([1, 4, 5])), (deque([2]), deque([1, 4, 5]))]
```